# "SublimeAutoPep8: some issue(s) were not fixed" such as E501

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm getting a soft warning in Python:

```
SublimeAutoPep8: some issue(s) were not fixed:
File "/Library/WebServer/dir/dir/filename.py", line 11: not fixed E501
File "/Library/WebServer/dir/dir/filename.py", line 33: not fixed E501
```

My current `AutoPep8.sublime-settings` is:

```
{
    "format_on_save": true,
     "max-line-length": 100,
}
```

I've tried adding the following config in `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
    "pep8": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "excludes": [],
        "ignore": [ "E251", "W291", "E501" ],
        "max-line-length": null,
        "select": ""
    },
```

doesn't seem to be right though.

What should I do to ignore these warnings? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should not be adding your AutoPep8 settings in `Preferences.sublime-settings` instead they should all be added to the `AutoPep8.sublime-settings` file which should be located in your Sublime Text `User` config directory.

Secondly I think you may have muddled up the settings of 2 different Sublime Text packages, those being [Auto​PEP8](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoPEP8) and [Python PEP8 Autoformat](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20PEP8%20Autoformat). Given the warning message you mention it seems reasonable to assume you installed `AutoPep8` but the settings you show are a combination of the 2 packages, see the default [AutoPep8.sublime-settings](https://github.com/wistful/SublimeAutoPEP8/blob/master/AutoPep8.sublime-settings) file and the default [pep8_autoformat.sublime-settings](https://bitbucket.org/StephaneBunel/pythonpep8autoformat/src/default/pep8_autoformat.sublime-settings) file. Both packages have an `ignore` setting but the `Python PEP8 Autoformat` package expects a list of strings, which is what you used, while the `AutoPep8` package expects a string of comma separated values, which is what I think you should have used.

You should be able to open your user `AutoPep8.sublime-settings` file using the Sublime Text menu:

```
Menu --> Preferences --> Package Settings --> AutoPep8 --> Settings – User
```

I suggest you try these `AutoPep8.sublime-settings` settings:

```js
{
    "format_on_save": true,
    "max-line-length": 100,
    // Crucially "ignore" uses a string with comma
    // separated values and not a list of strings.
    "ignore": "E251, W291, E501"
}
```